# how to use dynamic data for draw and display graph in my web page using php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html, google-visualization

I have a project in which i want to show a graph for profit of user per day.

Here I have code in which graph is displayed in my page using static data.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['day', 'profit' ],
          ['1',  10000],
          ['2',  10200],
          ['3',  9100],
          ['4',  9500]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

now, I want to fetch this data of profit and day from database in mysql & use that data for drawing graph.

Is there any way for make it dynamic like this way using php?
thank you for helping..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: use php to write variables into your existing javascript i.e.

```
<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';

// get 'myvalue' from database...

echo "var myvalue=".$myvalue.";";
echo '</script>'
?>
... rest of page including your javascript
```

If you want it more dynamic, use php to read your database and write the data in JSON format then xmlHTTPrequest that from your javascript.